# Easy approach for the expected number of dice throws to achieve a run of identical numbers

Tags: probability, probability-theory, markov-chains, stopping-times

In a hypothetical world, consider a dice which has $k$ faces labelled from 1 to $k$ and the probability that any face comes up is the same i.e. $1/k$. We use $X_t$ to denote the number that comes up in the $t$-th throw. Given $m\in\Bbb N^+$, and define the number of throws until a run of $m$ identical numbers:
$$N:=\inf_{t>0}\{X_{t-m+1},\cdots,X_t \text{ are identical}\}$$
Then what is $\Bbb E(N)$?

My thought: let $A_n$ be event that we have achieved a run of $n$ identical numbers, and $\Bbb E(N\mid A_n),\,n<m$ be the expected *additional* throws we need to achieve an $m$-run. Then we have:

\begin{align}
\Bbb E(N\mid A_m)&=0\\
\Bbb E(N\mid A_n)&=1+\frac1k\Bbb E(N\mid A_{n+1})+\frac{k-1}{k}\Bbb E(N\mid A_1),\quad 1\le n \le m-1\\
\Bbb E(N)&=\Bbb E(N\mid A_1)+1
\end{align}
Then the we only have to solve (1), (2) for $\Bbb E(N\mid A_1)$, since (3) is trivial. So it's $m$ equations and $m$ unknowns and we just have to solve this linear system.

This method is perfectly okay, but it is slow by hand even for relatively small $k,m$. Does there exist any other significantly slicker approach that can lead to a solution easily obtainable by hand, say in an interview?

Comment: This is crazy, we were pondering the exact same question a couple of days ago playing Dungeons and Dragons :)

Comment: It seems this question has appeared at the following [MSE link](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3174475/).

Comment: @MarkoRiedel indeed, the questions are the same. But it seems the answer has quite a lot of algebra and may not be solvable by hand say within one or two minutes. Since the answer happens to be $(k^m-1)/(k-1)$ (per my notation), I assume there must be a clever trick with which the problem neatly reduces to a geometric summation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a way that is a little simpler (I think) than the direct approach.
It requires two main steps.

First we have to show that the expected value $\mathbb E(N)$ is finite.
One way is to compare it to the expected number of rolls if we say the rolls can only end with $m$ consecutive identical rolls preceded by a multiple of $m$ rolls.
The number of rolls then has a geometric distribution  with a finite expectation.
Our random variable is different in that we accept $m$ consecutive identical rolls preceded by any number of rolls, not just a multiple of $m,$ so it has an expected value that is no greater than the other variable's.

Now consider the first run of identical rolls. The run has a length of at least one (the very first roll always matches itself!) and has no upper limit on its length, but we are only interested in lengths up to $m$ rolls.
(We do not need to consider more than $m$ rolls, because at $m$ rolls we have an $m$-run.)

In the cases where the first run has length $t$ where $t < m$, the conditional expectation $\mathbb E(N \mid \text{first run has length $t$})$ is
$t + \mathbb E(N).$
The probability of each such case is $(k-1)k^{-t}.$
The only other case to consider is the case where $t \geq m,$
in which case the conditional expectation is $m.$
The probability of that case is $k^{-(m-1)}.$
So by the law of total expectation,

\begin{align}
\mathbb E(N)
&= \left(\sum_{t = 1}^{m-1} (t + \mathbb E(N)) \frac{k-1}{k^t}\right)
   + m\frac{1}{k^{m-1}} \\
&= (k-1) \left(\sum_{t = 1}^{m-1} \frac{t}{k^t}\right)
 + (k-1) \mathbb E(N) \left(\sum_{t = 1}^{m-1} \frac{1}{k^t}\right)
 + \frac{m}{k^{m-1}}.
\end{align}

Now we have some familiar series to work with, although the fact that they are finite series forces us to do some extra work.
Recalling that $\sum_{t = 1}^\infty (1/k^t) = 1/(k-1)$
and $\sum_{t = 1}^\infty (t/k^t) = k/(k-1)^2,$

\begin{align}
\sum_{t = 1}^{m-1} \frac{t}{k^t}
&= \left(\sum_{t = 1}^\infty \frac{t}{k^t}\right)
  - \left(\sum_{t = m}^\infty \frac{t}{k^t}\right) \\
&= \left(\sum_{t = 1}^\infty \frac{t}{k^t}\right)
  - \left(\frac{m-1}{k^{m-1}} \left(\sum_{t = 1}^\infty \frac{1}{k^t}\right)
          + \frac{1}{k^{m-1}} \left(\sum_{t = 1}^\infty \frac{t}{k^t}\right)\right)\\
&= \frac{k}{(k-1)^2}
  - \left(\frac{m-1}{k^{m-1}(k-1)} + \frac{k}{k^{m-1}(k-1)^2} \right) \\
&= \frac{k^m - (m - 1)(k - 1) - k}{k^{m-1}(k-1)^2} \\
&= \frac{k^m - 1 - m(k - 1)}{k^{m-1}(k-1)^2}.
\end{align}

And there is also the better-known result

\begin{align}
\sum_{t = 1}^{m-1} \frac{1}{k^t}
&= \left(\sum_{t = 1}^\infty \frac{1}{k^t}\right)
  - \left(\sum_{t = m}^\infty \frac{1}{k^t}\right) \\
&= \left(1 - \frac{1}{k^{m-1}}\right)\left(\sum_{t = 1}^\infty \frac{1}{k^t}\right)\\
&= \frac{k^{m-1} - 1}{k^{m-1}(k-1)}.
\end{align}

Putting this together,

\begin{align}
\mathbb E(N)
&= \frac{k^m - 1 - m(k - 1)}{k^{m-1}(k-1)}
 + \frac{k^{m-1} - 1}{k^{m-1}} \mathbb E(N) 
 + \frac{m}{k^{m-1}}.
\end{align}

Multiply through by $k^{m-1}$ and simplify:

\begin{align}
k^{m-1} \mathbb E(N)
&= \frac{k^m - 1 - m(k - 1)}{k-1} + (k^{m-1} - 1) \mathbb E(N) + m\\
&= \left(\frac{k^m - 1}{k-1} - m\right) + (k^{m-1} - 1) \mathbb E(N) + m.
\end{align}

Canceling some terms and collecting $\mathbb E(N)$ on the left,

\begin{align}
\mathbb E(N) &= \frac{k^m - 1}{k-1}.
\end{align}

---

And as yet another way of looking at it,
when you throw the die for the first time, or whenever you throw a number different from the previous number, starting a new run,
the probability that this run will be an $m$-run (or longer) is $k^{-(m-1)}.$
The number of runs prior to the successful run is therefore a (shifted) geometric distribution with support on $t = \{0, 1, 2, \ldots\}$ and expected value $k^{m-1}-1.$

Within each of the runs prior to the successful run, the distribution of the length of the run is a kind of truncated geometric distribution,
that is, if $X$ is the length of the run then 
$$
\mathbb P(X=t) =
 \frac1{\sum_{u = 1}^{m-1} \frac{k-1}{k^u}} \left( \frac{k-1}{k^t} \right).
$$
But
$$
\sum_{u = 1}^{m-1} \frac{k-1}{k^u} = (k - 1)\frac{k^{m-1} - 1}{k^{m-1}(k-1)}
= \frac{k^{m-1} - 1}{k^{m-1}},
$$
so
$$
\mathbb P(X=t) = \frac{k^{m-1}}{k^{m-1} - 1} \left( \frac{k-1}{k^t} \right).
$$

The expected length of the run (conditioned on it being a run of length less than $m$) is
\begin{align}
\sum_{t = 1}^{m-1} t\mathbb P(X=t)
 &= \frac{k^{m-1}(k-1)}{k^{m-1} - 1} \sum_{t = 1}^{m-1} \frac{t}{k^t} \\
&= \frac{k^{m-1}(k-1)}{k^{m-1} - 1} 
    \left( \frac{k^m - 1 - m(k - 1)}{k^{m-1}(k-1)^2}\right) \\
&=  \frac{k^m - 1 - m(k - 1)}{(k^{m-1} - 1)(k-1)}. \\
\end{align}

But we expect $k^{m-1}-1$ such runs, so the total number of expected rolls is
$$ (k^{m-1}-1)\sum_{t = 1}^{m-1} t\mathbb P(X=t)
= \frac{k^m - 1 - m(k - 1)}{k-1} = \frac{k^m - 1 }{k-1} - m.
$$

Add $m$ for the $m$ consecutive identical rolls at the end, and the total is
$$ \frac{k^m - 1 }{k-1} .$$

Comment: Thanks. Actually I later found that my conditional expectation recursion approach isn't that much complicated after rearranging some terms. I also arrived at the geometric summation answer.

Comment: When I say "a little simpler" I mean in comparison to the general answer given under the linked question, not your method. And perhaps I should put more emphasis on "little".